# How to ensure that a controllers action is only being called once in sails.js app ..?

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I am trying to implement user authentication in my sails app.. But I am encountering a problem in different controllers that their action are being called twice.. I have checked from my browser and the request is only being sent once.. Here is an example..

```
 // api/controllers/AuthController.js
 ...
 logout: function (req, res) {
       console.log("Loggin out");
       req.logOut();
       res.json({message: 'Logged out succesfully'});

  },
...
```

Following is my `config/routes.js` file. (using get for many action just for sake of ease for testing api..)

```
module.exports.routes = {

  // By default, your root route (aka home page) points to a view
  // located at `views/home/index.ejs`
  // 
  // (This would also work if you had a file at: `/views/home.ejs`)
  '/': {
    view: 'home/index'
  },

  // testing the api
  'get /users/check' : 'UserController.test',
  'get /login' : 'AuthController.process',
  'get /logout' : 'AuthController.logout',
  'get /signup': 'UserController.add',
  'get /verify/username/:username?' : 'UserController.checkUsername',
  'get /verify/email/:email?' : 'UserController.checkEmail',

  // add friend 
  'get /:user?/addfriend': 'FriendController.addFriend',

  // accept request
  'get /:user?/friendrequest/:request?/accept': 'FriendController.acceptRequest',
};
```

I have applied the isAuthenticated policy on this action.. which is like

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log("Valid User");
        return next();
    }
    else {
        console.log("User not logged in");
        return res.json({error: "Please login"});
    }
};
```

No whenever I call `<myhost>/logout` I get the following json back..

```
{
  "error": "Please login"
}
```

and here is the output on the server..

```
Valid User
Loggin out
User not logged in
```

This means that my controller's action is being called twice.. and this is not the problem with only this controller. The UserController.add action has the same problem. I seem to be doing every thing fine but I don't know where this problem is coming from. Can any one suggest how can I debug it . Or what could be the root of the problem. As far as I have check..

1. Browser is not sending the request twice.
2. The Controller's action is being called twice and so are the middleware assosiated with it.

Comment: I added a `return` at the end of the action and now it is only being called once.. But I am still not sure why was it called twice..

Answer (score 0):

Oh i have the same Problem a few weeks ago.

Sails also call the middleware on static files (like your styles.css). Console.log the req-object than you see what your browser requested.

There a two Ways to handle this Problem:

1.) Try to set skipAssets: true in your route (see: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html)

2.) In your policy add an if-condition to skip assets (like "*.js", "*.css" and so on).

Comment: I am talking about actions not assets